# how to center div on a fullpage.js slide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I'm using the fullPage.js plugin taken from here http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#secondPage . There is a possibility to create the vertical slides and I'm doing so, however, when I use the following html code:

```
<div class="section" id="section2">
        <div class="slide" id="slide1">
        <div id="logocontainer">
            <div class="help1">

                <div id="about_img">
                    London<br>
                    Paris<br>
                    Tokyo<br>
                </div>

                <div id="about_txt">
                    <h2>London</h2>
                    <p>
                    London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,
                    with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                    Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia,
                    its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.
                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="slide" id="slide2">

        <!--    <img src="img/R1.png" alt="a" id="stand-one" /> -->
        </div>

        <div class="slide" id="slide3">
            <h1>Slide 3</h1>
        <!--    <img src="img/R1.png" alt="a" id="stand-one" /> -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the css code:

```
.help1  #about_img{
    line-height:30px;
    height:660px;
    width:400px;
    float:left; 
    background-color: #eeffaa;
}
.help1 #about_txt{
    height:660px;
    width:500px;
    float:left;      
}
    #logocontainer{
       position: absolute;
       top: 20%;
       margin-top: -35px;/* half of #content height*/
       left: 0;
       width: 100%;
    }
    .help1 {  
       margin:0;
       height: 660px;
       width: 900px;
       background-color: #b0c4de;
    }
```

my content of the div is at the very left site of slide1 (thanks to margin: 0;). I would like to center this div inside the slide, but when I change

```
.help1 {  
           margin:0;
           height: 660px;
           width: 900px;
           background-color: #b0c4de;
        }
```

to

```
.help1 {  
           margin-left:auto;
           margin-right: auto;
           height: 660px;
           width: 900px;
           background-color: #b0c4de;
        }
```

then my div is centered, but not on the slide1, but between all slides - so since I have three of them now, my div is in the middle of the second slide. I would like to center the div on slide1 and then center 2 other divs on 2 other slides - is that even possible?

Comment: If you add to your `help1` class the rule `top: 0 ` does it changes anything?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, after addint `top: 0;` to `help1` (and leaving the margin 0) nothing changed, the content is still on the left side of the 1st dive

Answer (score 1):

Use a relative position for the slide:

```
.fp-slide{
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Plugin have already added this css although it is not vertically aligned in middle.